# Github - link to function in source

Tags: github, hyperlink, markdown, anchor

I know I can have anchors to a certain line, but if the source changes that line might become irrelevant. Example:

`...source.php#L33` < line 33 may become line 40 later :(

Is there some way to tell GitHub to link to a certain function or property from the source, without specifying the line?

(The source is written in PHP code.)

Comment: It might be worth raising a ticket for this, it'd be very useful - I would imagine Github have a way of accepting feature suggestions. They'd have to implement a language parser to understand function/method definitions (and they would probably wish to add several, to remain language agnostic) so it's likely not a trivial undertaking `:)`.

Comment: I solved this by linking to the file instead the line of code. At least with this method you can route where's defined that function.

Answer (score 21):

AFAIK, no, but you can link to a certain revision of the file, and thus, you can know for sure that line will always point at the start of the function.

The URL looks like `/{user}/{repo}/blob/{hash}/{file}#L{line}`

To get it, click "Commits", select the last commit, click "Browse code", and find your file and line as usual.

[documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet#linking-to-markdown)

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can. Newer browsers support highlighting a portion of text and scrolling to it.

Example: [common.c#:~:text=static%20ssize_t%20led_current_store](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9e87a8da747bf72365abb79e6f64fcca955b4f56/drivers/leds/leds-lp55xx-common.c#:%7E:text=static%20ssize_t%20led_current_store)

All you have to do is to add this to the end of your URL:

> #:~:text=function_name

Some browsers do not support this, though: https://caniuse.com/url-scroll-to-text-fragment

Enjoy!

Comment: Good solution. But it did not work when I clicked the link in readme - GitHub loads it dynamically in the same tab. But works when opening in a new tab.